# I'm trying to make an rcpp package on windows 10 following the guide Instructions for Creating Your Own R Package

Tags: r, windows-10, rcpp, r-package

I'm trying to make an rcpp package on windows 10 following the [MIT guide](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjumvTKveTyAhWmaDABHQ5ICCwQFnoECAQQAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fweb.mit.edu%2Finsong%2Fwww%2Fpdf%2Frpackage_instructions.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0jHWALZod_ngv4urh6QrFW.) as follows:

```
library(Rcpp)
Rcpp.package.skeleton("Auxilio", cpp_files = "auxiliar_pi2.cpp", example_code = FALSE)
compileAttributes("Auxilio", verbose=TRUE)

library(tools)
package_native_routine_registration_skeleton("Auxilio", character_only = FALSE)

library(devtools)
build("Auxilio")
install("Auxilio")
```

However, in the last step (7. Compile your package) I got this output:

```
   *√  checking for file 'C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Scripts\20212\PI-2---ABC-for-SFA\codes\Juan\Auxilio/DESCRIPTION' ...
    -  preparing 'Auxilio':
    √  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
    -  cleaning src
    -  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
    -  checking for empty or unneeded directories
    -  building 'Auxilio_1.0.tar.gz'
       
    Running "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.1/bin/x64/Rcmd.exe" INSTALL \
      "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWgM8jk/Auxilio_1.0.tar.gz" \
      --install-tests 
    * installing to library 'C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/R/win-library/4.1'
    * installing *source* package 'Auxilio' ...
    ** using staged installation
    ** libs
    
    *** arch - i386
    "C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/Rcpp/include'        -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
    "C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/Rcpp/include'        -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c auxiliar_pi2.cpp -o auxiliar_pi2.o
    "C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/Rcpp/include'        -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c init.c -o init.o
    C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o Auxilio.dll tmp.def RcppExports.o auxiliar_pi2.o init.o -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.1/bin/i386 -lR
    C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: init.o:init.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `R_init_Auxilio'; RcppExports.o:RcppExports.cpp:(.text+0xc0): first defined here
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    no DLL was created
    ERROR: compilation failed for package 'Auxilio'
    * removing 'C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/Auxilio'
    Error in (function (command = NULL, args = character(), error_on_status = TRUE,  : 
      System command 'Rcmd.exe' failed, exit status: 1, stdout & stderr were printed*
```

The cpp file doesn't have compiling issues. I'll be very gratefull if someone help me, I tried many things but nothing work. Here is a short example of the rcpp file:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double moment_cpp(NumericVector x, int order, bool central){
  int n = x.length();
  double m = 0;
  if (central){
    m = mean(x);
  }
  double cont = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    cont = cont + pow(x(i) - m, order);
  }
  return cont / n;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double Coelli_cpp(NumericVector residuals){
  const int n = residuals.length();
  double m2;
  double m3;
  double M3T;
  
  m2 = moment_cpp(residuals, 2, 0);
  m3 = moment_cpp(residuals, 3, 1);
  M3T = m3 / sqrt(6*pow(m2,3) / n);
  
  return M3T;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector Etas_cpp(NumericVector priors, int n){
  Function rhalfnorm("rhalfnorm");
  Function rnorm("rnorm");
  
  const double sigma_v = priors[0];
  const double sigma_u = priors[1];
  const double b0 = priors[2];
  
  NumericVector v_sin = rnorm(n, 0, sigma_v);
  NumericVector u_sin = rhalfnorm(n, pow(sigma_u,-1)*pow(M_PI_2, 0.5));
  NumericVector eps_sin = b0 + v_sin - u_sin;
  
  NumericVector eta_sin = {mean(eps_sin), var(eps_sin), Coelli_cpp(eps_sin)};
  return eta_sin;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal example `auxiliar_pi2.cpp` file?

Comment: What exactly does “doesn’t have compiling issues” mean? How did you check that?

Comment: Try `roxygen2` package

Comment: You have, as the error message shows, multiple `init.c` declarations. Try the steps above, but without `package_native_routine_registration_skeleton`.  As others noted. your sources would help.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MrFlick I just put it in the original question.

Comment: @Roland I mean that I can source the file with `Rcpp::sourceCpp()` and call the functions (in `auxiliars_pi2.cpp`) manually without problem.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Wow, thank you a lot for your help, that solved my problem. I am new in this world of rcpp and parallel computing, and your webinar _Rcpp Workshop 2020-06-05_ was very helpful.

If you let me ask you another question, I'm currently developing a practical research of approximate bayessian computing for stochastic frontier analysis, so efficient codes are needed. Which parallelization package do you recommend me? Currently, I'm using the rcpp functions from the library Auxilio with the package doParallel.

Comment: @Community Thank you for your advice, I would take it into account for future questions.